# Show comments based on user role in front end

Tags: customization, user-roles, comment-form, comments

I want to allow commenting on a custom post type by a specific user role. And a user can see only his comments only.

Scenario is

e.g User roles are student and instructor. The Student can comment on a lesson, which is a custom post type. An instructor can see his comment and then reply on it.
Same the same student John can see only his comments and replies on his comments by his instructor.

I used the [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167250/prevent-contributor-to-show-comment-list) for reference also using the [comment_form](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form) for reference.

Comment: Please [merge your accounts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). You should **not** use a second account to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```
$args = array('post_author' => get_current_user_id(),);
$comments = get_comments( $args );
$list_args = array(
   'reverse_top_level' => false 
);
wp_list_comments( $list_args, $comments );
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?